# Treeview Tkinter widget - clickable links

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have ten links in my treeview widget (http://www.example.com, http://www.example1.com and so on). It is plain text inserted into treeview. Is it possible to make it clickable? How can I convert text into links? Is it possible inside treeview widget?

This is a part of my treeview:
[image: treeview]

I would like to make those lines clickable links (like in normal browser). Simply click, open default browser and go to page (http://dieta.pl/ for example).

Here is example of my code (a part):

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
from google import search
from urlparse import urlparse
from SiteCrawler import SiteCrawler
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
# from Tkinter.font import Font


class Main(Frame):

def __init__(self):
    self.fraza = None
    self.master = tk.Tk()
    if os.name == 'nt':
        self.master.state('zoomed')
    else:
        self.master.wm_attributes('-zoomed', 1)
    self.master.title('Site crawler')
    self.master.geometry("800x600+600+200")

    # Frame głowny
    self.f = Frame(self.master)
    self.f.place(relx=.5, rely=.35, anchor="c")

    # Label do wpisania frazy
    L1 = Label(self.master, text=u"Wpisz frazę", font="Verdana 15 bold")
    L1.grid(in_=self.f, row=1, column=2)

    # Entry box do wpisania frazy
    self.phrase = Entry(self.master, font="Verdana 15 bold",
                        justify=CENTER)
    self.phrase.grid(in_=self.f, row=1, column=3, columnspan=3)

    # Button do zatwierdzenia frazy
    Bt1 = Button(self.master, text=u'Wczytaj frazę',
                 command=lambda: self.results(self.phrase.get()), width=20)
    Bt1.grid(in_=self.f, row=2, column=3, columnspan=3)

    # ttk.tree widget
    tree_cols = ('Lp', 'Url', 'Fraza w Title',
                 'Fraza w description', 'Fraza w Keywords',
                 'Fraza w H1', 'Fraza w H2', 'Fraza w całej stronie')
    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=tree_cols,
                             show='headings', height=10)

    for i in tree_cols:
        self.tree.heading(i, text=i)

    self.tree.column('Lp', width=50, anchor=CENTER)
    # self.tree.heading("two", text="Fraza w Title")
    # self.tree.heading("three", text="Fraza w Description")
    # self.tree.heading("four", text="Fraza w Description")

    self.tree.grid(in_=self.f, row=4, column=1, columnspan=4, sticky=NSEW)

    self.master.mainloop()

def results(self, phrase):
    Crawler = SiteCrawler()
    self.fraza = phrase

    domains = []
    for i in search(phrase, stop=10):
        print i
        parsed_url = urlparse(i)
        domain = '{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}/'.format(uri=parsed_url)
        if domain not in domains:
            domains.append(domain)

    for index, url in enumerate(domains[:10]):
        h = ['h1', 'h2']
        Crawler.load_url(url, self.fraza)
        Crawler.title()
        Crawler.get_description()
        Crawler.get_keywords()
        for i in h:
            Crawler.count_H(i)
        Crawler.all_keywords()

        self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=(
            index + 1, url, Crawler.title(), Crawler.get_description(),
            Crawler.get_keywords(), Crawler.count_H('h1'),
            Crawler.count_H('h2'), Crawler.all_keywords()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
    main.results()
```

Comment: Can you provide example code? Also explain what functionality you want when double clicking the URL. Or do you simply want to be able to add it to the clipboard. Edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 4):

For each widget, you can [bind](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) Python functions and methods to events.`Bind` a function to your `treeview`.You need to bind your tree,add this in  `__init__` function:

```
self.tree.bind("<Double-1>", self.link_tree)
```

Create a function:

```
def link_tree(self,event):
    input_id = self.tree.selection()
    self.input_item = self.tree.item(input_id,"text")

    #for opening the link in browser
    import webbrowser
    webbrowser.open('{}'.format(self.input_item))
    #do whatever you want
```